# Remove first row from DataTable using LINQ Skip()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to remove the first row from a DataTable using LINQ's `Skip()` method.  So far I have

```
EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> erc = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(1);
```

but that throws a syntax error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What am I missing? The goal for having it in EnumerableRowCollection is so that I can then do another call:

```
DataTable myDataTableMinusFirstRow = erc.Any() ? erc.CopyToDataTable() : myDataTable.Clone();
```

I know there are other ways of doing this, such as deleting rows without skip, but this is more or less for learning purposes how to use skip better.

Comment: `"but that throws a syntax error"` - And the error is... ?

Comment: *but that throws a syntax error.* What error? What does it actually say.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Try adding '.CopyToDataTable()' function call at end of Skip() to get a new table without first row.

Comment: .CopyToDataTable() doesn't work. (still syntax error).  That would work on a DataTable type but not EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>.  Normally that's what I would want but if the resulting table has no rows, it would crash trying to convert a no-record collection into a datatable. .... I think.

Comment: Well before skipping 1, check if DataTable is not null and row count is > 0. Then do: var rowColl = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(1)

Comment: _var erc = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(1);_ no hassle here.

Comment: Seriously?  -1? At least step up and state your reason you coward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to `EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>`.

You need to create a new `EnumerableRowCollection` with the `DataRows` inside that `IEnumerable<T>` or change the variable type accordingly.

Just change the line to:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> erc = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(1);
```

Than you can use `erc.CopyToDataTable()` to instantiate a `DataTable` with those rows.

Comment: Thank you.  That actually accomplishes what I wanted to by using the following line of code: DataTable myDataTableMinusFirstRow = erc.Any() ? erc.CopyToDataTable() : myDataTable.Clone();